# Showing that $z=(0,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are limit points of the graph of $\cos(1/x)$ for all -1\le y\le 1

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2} : y = cos(1/x)\}$ be the graph of the continuous function 
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
f:&(0,+\infty)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R} \\
&x&\mapsto&\cos(1/x)\end{array}
$$
and $J = \{(0,y) : -1\le y\le 1\}$. I want to prove that all $z = (0,y)$ in $J$ are such that $d(z, X)= \inf\{d(z,x), x\in X\} = 0$.

My attempt: I tried using in $\mathbb{R^2}$ the metric $d(x,y) = \max\{ |x_1 - y_1|, |x_2 - y_2|\}$. Fix $z\in J$. It is immediate that $0\le d(z, X)$. So given $c>0$, I must show that exist some $x\in X$ such that $d(z,x)<c$. I'm able to show it for $c>1$ but I'm stuck with the case $c\le 1$. Any help?

Comment: You *tried* to use that metric? Is that the metric that you are supposed to use or not? The statement depends upont the metric.

Comment: I can use any metric that is equivalent to the Euclidean metric

Answer (score 1):

Take $y\in[-1-1]$. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, pick $x_n\in[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$, such that $\cos(x_n)=y$. Then $\left(\frac1{x_n},y\right)\in X$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{x_n},y\right)=(0,y)$, for each metric equivalent to the Euclidian metric.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is equivalent to asking does J belong to the closure of $X$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. But to your question: Let $z \in J$ and $c > 0$. We know that the cosine function gets every value in [-1,1] in each interval $(x, x+ 2\pi]$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence there exists $y\in (c^{-1}, c^{-1}+ 2\pi]$ where $(0,\cos y) = z$. Define $x = \frac{1}{y}$.

Notice that $x\in (0, c)$ and $(0,\cos \frac{1}{x}) = z.$  Now

$$\left|\left(x, \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) - z\right| = |(x, 0)| < c.$$

Thus $d(z, X) < c$ and hence the statement.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get why $x$ between $\frac{2}{2\pi n + \pi}$ and $\frac{2}{2\pi n + 5\pi}$ will cover all values in $[-1,1]$. I know that cosine gets all values in $[x, x+2\pi]$, but cos(1/x) is not periodic in this manner so I didn't get how did you got it from this